# MUI produces a bunch of empty style blocks

Tags: material-ui

I'm using `makeStyles` for adding my own styles on top of MUI components. I found out in the header, there are a massive amount of empty `<style data-jss data-meta="makeStyles">`. I wonder where I am doing it wrong.

[image]